# Monero Ring Signature data

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, ring-signatures

Is it possible to get all the data of all the transaction with all its ring signatures using either the **monero-wallet or API**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. See [get_transactions](https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_transactions) from the daemon RPC.

Comment: can i used python to make the rpc call????

Comment: Yes. It's just a JSON RPC request (http).

Comment: I was just wondering there are more than 50 ring signatures for a transaction. But when i was reading at places it consisted of only 10 or so ring signatures? Can you help me with this?

Comment: Ringsize in latest version is now 11 (so 10 decoys).

Comment: so technically there should be only 11 right??? But when i do get_transactions it is returning me almost more than 50 signatures(hash)